# ScrollView that does not render views that aren't visible

Tags: android, scrollview

I am attempting to improve the amount time it takes to fill the items into the ScrollView. If I hard code the height (not in pixels of course) of every `RelativeLayout` in the `LinearLayout` in the other `LinearLayout` in the `ScrollView`... can I get ScrollView to display the visible ones first and then when they are displayed to load up the rest later? The ScrollView should start off scrolled to a specific location.. not just the top of the screen. Now if we have to load from the top that is OK because there is about one third above the visible area and the rest below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ViewStub to inflate extra items only when you need it, but it sounds like you are describing what ListView does already.

Comment: +1, I am also under an impression the ListView is what is needed here.

Comment: ViewStub works in ScrollView if it is a child of a fixed dimension ViewGroup. Also, the developer has to detect when to render. It is not automatic. ListView works but my case had extra drawables and various heights (even though they were fixed, they were not all the same) and there were load more buttons on the top and bottom. Maybe I could have gotten ListView to work. My was to make each view more efficient (I used nested drawable backgrounds instead of nested ViewGroup) and to modify the app so it could display less than what was loaded. Each ViewGroup adds to the CPU time required.